# Nginx + LAMP disable allow from 8080

Tags: apache, nginx, lamp

I have configured **Nginx (frontend) + LAMP**, multiple domains (virtual hosts).

**Nginx** listen on **80** port, **Apache** on **8080**

this is my config for **Nginx**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        client_max_body_size 1000m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout 90;
        proxy_send_timeout 90;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;

        proxy_buffer_size 4k;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 10m;
    }

    location ~ ^/phpMyAdmin/(.*\.(js|css|gif|jpg|png))$ {
        alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/$1;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|flv|rtf|js|swf|iso)$ {
        root /var/www/html;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        client_max_body_size 1000m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout 90;
        proxy_send_timeout 90;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;

        proxy_buffer_size 4k;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 10m;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|flv|rtf|js|swf|iso)$ {
        root /var/www/example.com;
    }
}
```

and this my conf **Apache**

```
Listen 8080
ServerName localhost
NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost _default_:8080>
    Options -Indexes
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

How to deny access from **example.com:8080** ?

example.com - nginx (frontend)

[image: http://i.imgur.com/AlebAMv.png]

example.com:8080 - apache

[image: http://i.imgur.com/vlTxLKS.png]

and what do you think my mistakes in the config? Thank you in advance!

Comment: How to close port 8080 on centOS?

Answer (score 0):

Either :

- Listen on `127.0.0.1:8080` instead of `*:8080`

Or

- Use `firewalld` on CentOS 7 or `iptables` on CentOS < 7 (except if you put iptables back on CentOS 7 of course).

Comment: It's work! Thanks, now i have new problem, after authorization in phpmyadmin redirect me to 8080 and page not available http://i.imgur.com/3PKOco5.png, how to fix?

Comment: @user2429282 Remove `proxy_redirect off;`

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! I LOVE YOU!)))

Comment: how to accept answer? not see button. still there is a problem with phpmyadmin transfer on 8080, my confgs is bad(